# UITableViewController to UITabBarController's DetailViewController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, storyboard

I have made a XML parser that list correctly in the UITableViewController. It passes a few details and also lat and long for the MKMap view. At first my setup was to go directly from the UITableViewController to the DetailViewController, this worked perfectly. It god the proper details from the XML for that selected option in the list.

Current setup:

```
Navigation Controller > Table View > Detail View Controller
```

I just want to rearrange the whole storyboard a bit. Instead of going directly to a DetailViewController I want it to be send to the Tab View.

New setup:

```
Navigation Controller > Table View > Tab Bar Controller - Detail View Controller 1
                                                       |_ Detail View Controller 2
```

According to my NSLOG the data from the Table View passed to the Tab Bar Controller, but not to the Detail View Controllers, is it anyway possible to lift that data to the Detail View Controllers?

No errors or warnings are shown. But here are some snippets from the code:

This is the Table View Controller, it sends the proper data from the segue to the next controller.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"StadionDetail"]) { 
    StadionDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; 
    detailViewController.theList = [app.listArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]];
  }
}
```

Then TabViewController correctly receives that data, but it doesn't lift that data over to the Detail View Controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you push a `UITabBarController` you would have to loop through its viewControllers and assign the data to each viewController.

something like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MyTabBarController"]) { 
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = [segue destinationViewController];
        for (MyFancyViewController *vc in [tabBarController viewControllers]) {
            vc.data = ...
        }
    }
}
```